# Failed to emerge python 2.7

Tags: python, gentoo

I'm trying to emerge python 2.7 on my gentoo server, somehow it's not installed any more.

```
eselect python list
Available Python interpreters:
  [1]   python3.3 *
```

If I try to emerge it like `emerge -a python:2.7` it'll fail with the error:

```
* ERROR: dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo failed (install phase):
 *   emake failed
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/work/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/work/Python-2.7.6'

>>> Failed to emerge dev-lang/python-2.7.6, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package dev-lang/python-2.7.6:

 * ERROR: dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo failed (install phase):
 *   emake failed
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-lang/python-2.7.6::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/work/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-lang/python-2.7.6/work/Python-2.7.6'

 * Regenerating GNU info directory index...
 * Processed 115 info files.

!!! existing preserved libs:
>>> package: dev-lang/python-2.7.5-r3
 *  - /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
 *      used by /usr/bin/b2 (dev-util/boost-build-1.52.0-r1)
 *      used by /usr/bin/bjam (dev-util/boost-build-1.52.0-r1)
 *      used by /usr/bin/vim (app-editors/vim-7.3.762)
 *      used by 44 other files
Use emerge @preserved-rebuild to rebuild packages using these libraries
```

Various sources mentioned a problem with the `readline` library so I masked the latest buggy version like someone else advised in [this](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-985366-start-0.html) forum post.

```
 Installed versions:  6.2_p1(02:03:23 PM 06/15/2014)
```

is now the latest installed version which shouldn't contain the bug.

Unfortunately the problem persists.

I uploaded the full build log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67c66e859b6625020493

Any idea what's wrong there?

Thank you!